# Source for Vilna Gaon saying that music can revive the dead?

Tags: sources-mekorot, music, vilna-gaon, resurrection-of-the-dead

I remember learning (and even found in the 2nd to last paragraph of [this article](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/torah-and-general-wisdom-teachings-gra)) that the Vilna Gaon said that music is so powerful that it's possible to resurrect the dead with it.

Anyone have the source where he said this **OR** (if not) an early source where this statement is attributed to the Gr"a?

Comment: There is some logic to this; many sefarim say that music is the language spoken in Shamayim. It would make sense that in the right hands it could summon a soul back to its deceased host.

Comment: Any sources for your statement? @DonielF

Comment: @Moshe Shem MiShmuel, Vayikra p. 71; Hachsharas Ha’avreichim 9; Imrei Tal, Ma’amar HaNiggun; Beis Yehudah on Ein Yaakov, Erchin 11a; most explicitly in Imrei Sha’ul, Inyanei Zemirah 43; Ya’aros Devash 2:7; Zohar, Vayakhel 196a; Matnas Chinam, Mo’adim p. 152. I could go on, but I think that’s enough.

Comment: Yay. Thanks a ton! @DonielF

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing the idea from the gemara in Sanhedrin that where do we know about techias hameissm from the Torah ,answer "Az Yashir" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source (AFAIK) for this quote is from the famed [short-timed] disciple of the Vilna Gaon, [R. Yisroel of Shklov](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_ben_Shmuel_of_Shklov) in his intro to Pe’at HaShulchan ([pg. 5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49511&st=&pgnum=8), last third of left column). Since the language isn’t unequivocal (IMO, at least) I won’t translate and only quote the relevant text:

> כה אמר, כל החכמות נצרכים לתורתינו הק׳ וכלולים בה וידעם כולם לתכליתם והזכירם אלגעברע ומשולשים והנדסה **וחכמת מוסיקא ושיבחה הרבה הוא היה אומר אז כי רוב טעמי תורה וסודות שירי הלוים וסודות תיקוני הזוהר א״א** (אי אפשר) **לידע בלעדה ועל ידה יכולים ב״א** (בני אדם) **למות בכלות נפשם מנעימותי׳ ויכולים להחיות מתים בסודות הגנוזים בתורה**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does he say that he got this teaching from the Gr"a?

Comment: @alicht I understand it to be a quote he heard from [R. Menahem Mendel of Shklov](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/menahem-mendel-shklov), a different [primary] disciple of the VG.

Comment: @alicht FTR, quite sure the VG wasn’t speaking of [the likes of] Phish :)

Comment: Not sure if Trey's guitar is powerful enough #fluffhead